# Why do I receive a bad/scrambled/garbled text message on websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, java-websocket

I have a websocket server based on Jetty(v 9.3.6) . 
Sometimes I receive a scrambled text message, in the way that it's combined from 2 separated text messages.
All messages I sent from client to server and vice versa are in JSON format.

For example I have this 2 separated messages:

```
{"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

and

```
{"e":"f","g":"h"}
```

Sometimes (not always) I receive something like this:

```
"b","c":"d"}
```

or

```
"b""g":"h"},"c":"d"}
```

It's either the incomplete message or a combination of 2 different incomplete messages.

I have noticed about this error when the JSON parser start throwing String parsing errors.

NOTE: I tried but failed to simulate this on localhost. On production server where I have around 600-1k connected clients and around 100k+ messages sent / day , this errors appears on 0.5-1% of the total sent messages.

NOTE 2: The clients are web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm that you have `permessage-deflate` active.

If you do, then you tripped on bug [485469](https://bugs.eclipse.org/485469) 
(*"permessage-deflate extension causes protocol error in Firefox/Chrome"*)

Either disable `permessage-deflate`, or upgrade to Jetty 9.3.7.v20160115

Comment: Hello @Joakim Erdfelt . I think I have permessage-deflate  enabled. I've upgraded to 9.3.7 but now some messages are not sent by the client(Chrome) If I downgrade to 9.3.6 it's working. The server is sending this header when the connection is made: Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate
Can you tell me how to disable permessage-deflate ? (I'm using an embedded jetty server , so if it's possible to disable from code)

Comment: nevermind. I figure it out. I'll check to see if this error happens in the next 2-3 days and I'll update the post. Thanks